# Why does my Promise definition gets executed?

Tags: javascript, constructor, promise

I am quite new with Promises and want to know why is it that my Promise definition gets executed without me calling a `.then()` or resolve on it.

```
var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
     console.log("Starting loader");
     resolve();
});
```

If you run the sample and see the console you will see the 'Starting loader' message.

https://jsfiddle.net/npqgpcud/

Comment: Your executor function *does* call `resolve()`.

Comment: @Pointy, I suppose the question revolves around the fact that _executor_ is executed immediately and synchronously when instantiating a promise, Domenic has given a ref below on the spec where it clearly says why

Comment: There is no trouble with this fact however. Even if promise was resolved _before_ `.then` was attached to it, still the handler attached with `.then` later will execute correctly

Comment: @KirillSlatin I understand that the .then will work correctly. Maybe I oversimplified my sample. I want to create a Promise that will evaluate a jQuery ajax but I want a generic one so that it may be a Promise wrapper around jQuery. So I need to define a generic Promise that will only get executed when it is called with some parameters, not at definition time. Thanks for commenting !

Comment: Well... in this case your question sounds misleading. Take a look towards `promisify` in bluebird. And yes, it's impossible to create a Promise object that you're going to call multiple times. You need function that creates a promise and returns it

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is simply how promises are defined. They run their executor function immediately. It's in the spec: [Promise(executor)](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-executor), step 9.

This is an instance of the [revealing constructor pattern](https://blog.domenic.me/the-revealing-constructor-pattern/); reading that might help you understand.

Comment: Thank you Domenic ! I didn't know it was defined as that. As I pointed out at a comment what I wanted was a generic Promise to function as a wrapper for jQuery ajax that could be called with different parameters for the ajax settings.

Comment: @AdriánE: Promises don't receive arguments. If you need parameters, then use a *function* that returns a promise.

Comment: Promise(executor) link is broken.

Answer (score 6):

That occurs because a promise *will* execute immediately and synchronously.

`.then()` add functions that will be executed when the promise is either fulfilled (`resolve` argument) or rejected (`reject` argument).

<sub>with info from comments by @Kirill Slatin</sub>